# Helper function to avoid repetitions of code

Tags: javascript

I have got 2 arrays, that are displayed on my page using `forEach` loop. I have created a separate functions for each, but they are very similar and I would like to avoid code repetition.

```
array.forEach(display);
array2.forEach(display2);


function display(item, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    itemProfile(item, this, i)
  });
}

function display2(driver, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper2');
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list2.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    itemProfile2(item, this, i)
  });
}
```

What would be the best way to do this? Can I add some code inside forEach loop? e.g:

```
array.forEach(display, () => {
   console.log()
 })
```

Comment: the only thing different is classlist and itemProfile callback, you could just add two parameters and combine it into one function.  organization will kind of depend on how the code works.  it looks like even itemProfile2 callback can be refactored.

Comment: You could pass additional info to your display function via an inline arrow function, e.g.: `array.forEach((item, index) => display(item, index, ‘wrapper2’))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just pass the element type as an argument. That way you can just use one function

```
arrayOne.forEach((item, i) => display(item, i, "wrapper"))
array2.forEach((item, i) => display(item, i, "wrapper2"))

function display(item, i, wrapperType) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add(wrapperType);
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    itemProfile(item, this, i)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `bind` to attach `this` scope and parameters

```
var bar = foo.bind(this, 1);
bar(2, 3);
```

will behave like:

```
var bar = (a, b) => foo(1, a, b);
bar(2, 3); // (executed in scope of `this`)
```

so you can use it to bind first parameter in `forEach`:

```
array.forEach(display.bind(this, itemProfile));
array2.forEach(display.bind(this, itemProfile2));


function display(listener, item, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    listener(item, this, i)
  });
}
```

but for the sake of readability it's better to make wrapper functions like:

```
array.forEach(display1);
array2.forEach(display2);

function display1(item, i) {
    display(itemProfile, item, i);
}

function display2(item, i) {
    display(itemProfile2, item, i);
}


function display(listener, item, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  const nameList = document.createElement('h2');
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    listener(item, this, i)
  });
}
```

even better - I don't know the rest of the code but check if the whole `itemListener` can be unified. this code looks like there is already some problem with the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

The only diff between `display1`, `display2` function is `wrapper` class name and the callback function. You can pass the `callback` function to forEach with different parameters.

```
className1 = "wrapper";
className2 = "wrapper2";
array.forEach((item, index) => display(item, index, className1, itemProfile));
array2.forEach((item, index) => display(item, index, className2, itemProfile2));

function display(item, index, cl, fn) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.classList.add(cl); // className
  const nameList = document.createElement("h2");
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    fn(item, this, index); // custom function
  });
}
```

Second way using bind, Move the item and index at last argument to `display` function.

```
className1 = "wrapper";
className1 = "wrapper2";

// Move the item and index at last
function display(cl, fn, item, index) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.classList.add(cl); // className
  const nameList = document.createElement("h2");
  nameList.textContent = item.name;
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(nameList);
  list1.appendChild(wrapper);
  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    fn(item, this, index); // custom function
  });
}
// Using bind:
const display1 = display.bind(this, "wrapper", itemProfile);
const display2 = display.bind(this, "wrapper2", itemProfile2);

array.forEach(display1);
array2.forEach(display2);
```